# Node JS cannot use multiple split and trim functions on string buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I im using ffmpeg in node js and would like to get outputed string:

```
frame=  986 fps=100 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:39.40 bitrate=N/A speed=4.01x
```

to parse into variables so that i can later query it into mysql database for later sorting and showing on datatables.

the problem is that this code in jsfiddle works as expected...but in node js i get this error when i use multiple split and trim functions:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot call method 'trim' of undefined
```

Here is what i try on node js converted from jsfiddle:

```
streams[id].stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    data = data.toString().split('=');
    var frame = data[1].trim().split(' ');
    console.log(frame[0]);
});
```

JSFIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/o32z7yb0/

UPDATE #2:
Using above code i get first split string i get this:

```
347 fps
```

so how can i remove fps in node js? if i call another:

```
datas[1].split(' fps');
```

i get 
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

```
streams[id].stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    var datas = data.toString().split('=');

    console.log(datas[1]);
});
```

Comment: Have you `console.log`ged the contents of data? Because ten bucks says there's no `=` and `data[1]` yields `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks..i upadated question #2 and i get output but i can't use two split functions on same string in node js this is what is strange to me...i know that i can use for each variable regex but i im not familiar with regex

Comment: In the function you have written here `data = data.toString().split('=');`. That overwrites the paramater `data`. Is that a typo error? Should it not be `var datas = data.toString().split('=');`?

Comment: Yes you are right..i added var datas to updated questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your data string looks like this:

```
var str = "frame=  986 fps=100 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=00:00:39.40 bitrate=N/A speed=4.01x";
```

Then you likely want to process it like so:

```
let parts = str

  // match will separate it out into an array of pieces
  .match(/[a-zA-Z]+\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z\/0-9\.\-:]+/g)

  // split each piece on the '=' with optional surrounding whitespace.
  .map(str => str.split(/\s*=\s*/)

  // put the name/value pairs into an object
  .reduce((acc, arr) => {
    let prop = arr[0];
    let val = arr[1];
    acc[prop] = val;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(parts); // { "frame": "896", "fps": "100", ...etc }
```

### Regex explanation:

```
[a-zA-Z]+ // match any letter one or more times
\s*       // match any whitespace char zero or more times
=         // match =
\s*       // same as above
[
  a-zA-Z  // match any letter
  0-9     // any number
  \/\.\-: // . : / any of those three
]+        // ... one or more times
g flag    // get all matches
```